# Assigning malloc output to an address? lvalue error

Tags: c, malloc, lvalue

Why is it not possible to assign the malloc output to the address of a struct?

## Case 1

This gives an lvalue error:

```
struct winErs
{
  int netds;
  char* blts;
};

void func_3(struct winErs gibble){

  printf("this is the address of the gibble %d \n", &gibble);  
  &gibble = malloc(sizeof(struct winErs));
} 


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct winErs simple_Case; 
  func_3(simple_Case);

  return 0;
}
```

## Case 2

This does not give an error:

```
struct winErs
{
  int netds;
  char* blts;
};

void func_3(struct winErs *gibble){

  printf("this is the address of the gibble %d \n", &gibble);  
  gibble = malloc(sizeof(struct winErs));
} 


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct winErs simple_Case; 
  func_3(&simple_Case);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a good explanation as to why this doesn't work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the language of the standard which talks about `lvalue`s and `rvalue`s ...

`gibble` already has an address. You cannot change that address. You can only change its value.

Only the value of a pointer can be changed so that it points to a different location in memory.

Even in **Case 2**, you are not changing the address of `simple_Case` in the function. You are only changing the value of the pointer in `func_3`. It is a local change in the function. It is a memory leak, BTW. The memory allocated by `malloc` is not visible to the calling function. Hence, the calling function has no way of deallocating it.

Answer (score 1):

In `func_3()` case2, `gibble` begins with the address of `main`'s `simple_Case`.  Later it takes on the value of the pointer return by `malloc()`.  Certainly nothing strange there, `gibble` is a pointer and its *value* changes as code proceeds.

In case1, code attempts to change the address of a variable with `&gibble = malloc()`.  The address of variables are not change-able.  Note that a variable may not even have an address if it was optimized to only exist as a processor's register.

Answer (score 1):

Because the location of a value is determined by the compiler.  It's not something you get to change by assignment or any other means. `&gibble` is the location of `gibble`.  It's not assignable in the same sense that `1 = 42;` would not change the value of the constant 1 to 42. Not assignable is the same as saying it's not an l-value.

To put it in practical terms, if you live at 1 Baker St., it would be silly to think your house would hop spontaneously across the street if someone decided to assign your address as 2 Baker St. instead.  The compiler is just telling you in its own quaint way of this silliness.

On the other hand `gibble` is the name of a location that's capable of storing the location of any other value.  (Well not exactly, but we won't get into the nits of memory alignment and C semantics.)  So the assignment works fine.